# Dell Latitude D830 and Windows 7 Video Drivers

Tags: windows-7, performance, nvidia-quadro

I just loaded Windows 7 x64 to a Dell Latitude D830 and it's working great, but the Windows Experience score is 3.3 on the Aero video performance.  The next lowest score is 4.9, so the video performance is dragging the score down quite a bit.  I've heard it should be better than that with the NVidia mobile Quadro NV140M card that's in there.  I loaded the 64-bit drivers directly from NVidia's site.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not missing anything at all. The Windows Experience score is quite strict in what it expects to calculate score. Unless you have some sort of indication of what the score is you would like to see, the actual score is fairly meaningless.

It is rare for me to see a graphics card give more then a 4.0 score in a notebook, unless your running an Alienware top of the range SLI.

IMHO The score is an indication but by no means a perfect indication of how well the card will perform. I have also seen a card's score drop between x86 and x64 installations. Unless your building this machine for high end gaming there should be no need to get the score higher, as it is more then sufficient to run day to day applications.

Answer (score 1):

I got a 3.5 rating on my Dell Latitude D830, but I am running the 32Bit version of Win7. I have been running this for several days and have not found any problems with Aero performance yet, so I think you would be fine on your rating.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had the same issue. Device manager lists video as "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" and there is no update through Windows or Dell. I noticed the problem because Areo wasn't running. Using HWiNFO32 a free hardware ID tool, my video was listed as "nVidia Quadro NV5 135M" a quick visit to nVidia's driver download page, bam, problem solved!

This problem didn't occur in the 32-Bit Windows 7, apparently Microsoft had a driver. Note the only real reason for a 64-Bit OS is if you have 4GB+ RAM installed.

My Driver-
http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/Windows/260.89/260.89_notebook_winvista_win7_64bit_international_whql.exe&lang=us&type=GeForce M